# Ajax pagination in joomla

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I am looking to implement an ajax based pagination system in joomla. anyone ever tried this before? And pointers or suggestions?

With joomla you cannot navigate away from the url by means of 'get'. This prohibits just about all pagination classes from working as most use a url modification to work(via get). So my alternatives are either post or ajax pagination, and ajax seems much easier to accomplish and will have a nicer looking result.

Any tutorials Ive tried havent worked out so well. I don't know if it really matters, but I'm using MySQLi.

Comment: You're really going to have to add some more details to this question.

Comment: As per the FAQ, this question is not fit for the StackOverflow format because it is too broad and can only be fully and correctly answered with an entire book. Please consider revising your question down to a little detail. If you have several questions, that's fine. Just be sure to create multiple questions instead of asking them all in the same question.

Comment: Having done a lot of work with joomla, I think it's a fair question, just perhaps mistagged. I don't have an answer, but would love to hear any responses as this would be wonderful to implement.

Answer (score 2):

AddFullAJAX plugin, that suggested in previous answer, tries make you site "fullajax'd" by default. But this can simple overwrite. Here a couple simple steps for configuration of this plugin for enable AJAX (correctly AHAH ;) ) pagination :

1. Set "Enable Positions update" to "Using fullajax_tmpl" (also do not forget install this template)
2. In the "Content CSS id" need set content id where placed you content
3. In "Advanced Options" in the "parameters for FullAjax" field need delete all, and put there next code:

```js
function wrapPager(){
  $$('div.pagination a').addEvent('click', function(){
    hax({url:this.href, id:fullAjaxId,nohistory:1, onload:wrapPager});
    return false;
 });
}
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  wrapPager()
})
```

Same you can do without plugin, just download and connect [FullAJAX](https://github.com/Fedik/FullAJAX) library in you template. Then use next example:

```
function wrapPager(){
  $$('div.pagination a').addEvent('click', function(){
    var url = this.href + '&tmpl=component'
    hax({url:url, id:'id-of-block-where-a-content',nohistory:1, onload:wrapPager});
    return false;
 });
}
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  wrapPager()
})
```

More about `hax()` can find on [wiki page](https://github.com/Fedik/FullAJAX/wiki/HAX---HtmlAjaX)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should then write a component/plugin and edit the template for AJAX uses ...
Since this is very difficult to achieve and consumes a lot of time, why don't you use Joomla 2.5 and use this great plugin : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/scripts/13293

And here's a little demo here: http://getsite.org.ua/jdemo/

**PS**: There might be some compatibility problems with the used modules/components so it's up to you to search/solve them :)

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion. We tried that extension, as great as it is, it didn't quite do what we needed it to. So we decided to write our own joomla/ajax/pagination system. If anyone wants it I'll gladly share it, but it wouldn't be too simple to implement, as it was written to suit our needs.

Comment: Glad to hear that you succesfully implemented ajax in joomla, maybe you should answer and "accept it" (for the community) ...

Comment: @MattRyan, I would really appreciate if you could share your code on here. Will come in very handy for me and other Joomla users out there as its very rare to see Ajax pagination. Please consider sharing your code or a download link. Regards

Comment: I would also appreciate this code, if you are happy to share it?